# How to create app with 2 view for different orientations?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

How to create app with 2 view for different orientations?
For landscape and portrait, i need 2 XIB. Own for each orietation?

Answer (score 0):

You can react on orientation changing with

```
willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:
```

Create an additional xib and set file owner to the class of your viewcontroller.

Create 2 viewcontroller with initWithNibName:

On willRotateToInterface replace your controller. For example by removing the fist One from your navigationcontroller and add the other one.

Hope it helps